# How to Specify an Ajax update ID when using a Programatic Model in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

**Problem:** Using a dynamic model to create a Primefaces component, such as a `Menubar` removes the ability to specify what components to be updated via Ajax within the JSF/XHTML page. It seems poor practice to hard code it in the Java back bean.

**Example:**

JSF:

```
<h:panelGroup id="updateDiv">
    <!-- components -->
</h:panelGroup>

<p:menubar model="#{backBean.model}" />
```

Back Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BackBean {
    private MenuModel model;

    public BackBean() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
        item.setUpdate("updateDiv");  // Here: hardcoded dependency on JSF page.
        item.setValue("Click Me.");
        model.addMenuItem(item);
    }

    public getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

Specifying the `updateDiv` in the `BackBean` couples it to the JSF page. This seems bad? Is it? And if so, what alternatives are there? Maybe using `<f:param/>` or something similar might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't have much trouble with that. Code on backing beans are usually coupled to the JSF pages anyway.

I'd put it in a constant with a meaningful name, though, something like:

```
private static final String CONTENT_PANEL_ID = "updateDiv";
```

There have been some discussion  here on SO already about how much coupling is to be allowed in the backing beans, specially regarding properties and methods.
I recommend reading through these, and making up your own mind:

- [Proper use of backing beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758814/proper-use-of-backing-beans)
- [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)
- [Making Distinctions Between Different Kinds of JSF Managed-Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223055/distinction-between-different-types-of-managed-beans)
- [JSF backing bean structure (best practices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746047/jsf-backing-bean-structure-best-practices)
- [Understanding JSF as a MVC framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111387/understanding-jsf-as-a-mvc-framework)